# Write chuck size into file

Tags: php, file, ini

Hei,

Can be possible in PHP to write into file using chucks size?

Eg: i want this array `$array = Array(0 => Array(1,3), 1=> Array(2,5))` to be written in file like this: [firstline] 1 3 [secondline] 2 5.

I've tried to use "for" for looping after count($array) and file_put_contents with flag APPEND but it is not working.

```
foreach ($controlSum->matrixA as $values) {

 #file_put_contents($my_file, print_r($values));
 for($i = 0; $i < count($controlSum->matrixA); $i++) {
    fwrite($my_file, implode(" ", $values), $i);
 }

}
```

I've tried with file_put_contents and also i don't want to serialize content.

10x,

Comment: Show your code. Questions that show no effort get downvoted and closed as too broad.

Answer (score 1):

If you tried appending then you are doing it inside the loop (wrong):

```
foreach($array as $values) {
    $result[] = implode(' ', $values) . PHP_EOL;
}
file_put_contents('/path/to/file.txt', $result);
```

Comment: @Oana Just a heads up, on SO the best way to say "thanks" for a helpful answer is by upvoting. And if the answer solved your problem you can accept the answer by clicking the checkmark next to it - this will imply to future users that this answer works. Neither of these are required, just standard procedures :)

Comment: `file_put_contents()` takes an array? Cool. What does it do with it? Join with `""` or EOL?